# How to disable Vs Code suggestions on Html tag innertext?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I want to disable Vs Code suggestions when i am writing a tag innertext.

thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click `Ctrl+Comma(,)`
Search for `Quick Suggestions` > Toggle the string ,comment option to `off`.
And what you are asking is not possible, either you can turn it off completely or adjust with its nature. Or You can try other IDE as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning off suggestions just for html with this setting:

```
"[html]": {
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  }
}
```

The html language server doesn't seem to consider innerText to be a string, so just turning off `"strings"` doesn't help.  That setting isn't affecting emmet suggestions.  But you should try it and see if any suggestions you might want are lost.  You will not get completion suggestions for `class`, `href`, etc. so it might not be an acceptable trade-off.  But emmet stuff like `div.myClass` do still work.